# Are there any existing methods for importing functions from other scripts without sourcing the entire script?

Tags: shell

I am working on a large shell program and need a way to import functions from other scripts as required without polluting the global scope with all the internal functions from that script.

UPDATE: However, those imported functions have internal dependancies. So the imported function must be executed in the context of its script.

I came up with this [solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133143/simple-import-system-for-a-large-shell-program) and wonder if there is any existing strategy out there and if not, perhaps this is a really bad idea?

[PLEASE TAKE A LOOK AT THE POSTED SOLUTION BEFORE RESPONDING](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133143/simple-import-system-for-a-large-shell-program)

example usage of my solution:

main.sh

```
import user get_name
import user set_name

echo "hello $(get_name)"
echo "Enter a new user name :"
while true; do
    read user_input < /dev/tty
done
set_name $user_input
```

user.sh

```
import state

set_name () {
    state save "user_name" "$1"
}

get_name () {
    state get_value "user_name"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while and it would appear that my [original solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133143/simple-import-system-for-a-large-shell-program) is the best one out there.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thn accept your own answer (this answer): It will not appear in the list of questions without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As one approach, you could put a comment in the script to indicate where you want to stop sourcing:

```
$ cat script
fn() { echo "You are running fn"; }
#STOP HERE
export var="Unwanted name space pollution"
```

And then, if you are using bash, source it like this:

```
source <(sed '/#STOP HERE/q' script)
```

`<(...)` is process substitution and our process, `sed '/#STOP HERE/q' script` just extracts the lines from script until the stop line is reached.

#### Adding more precise control

We can select particular sections from a file if we add both start and stop flags:

```
$ cat script
export var1="Unwanted name space pollution"
#START
fn1() { echo "You are running fn1"; }
#STOP
export var2="More unwanted name space pollution"
#START
fn2() { echo "You are running fn2"; }
#STOP
export var3="More unwanted name space pollution"
```

And then source the file like this:

```
source <(sed -n '/#START/,/#STOP/p' script)
```

Comment: It certainly is one way, however not as comprehensive/flexible as the solution i posted.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Different solutions have different strong points and I'm sure that your solution fits your requirements superbly.  As I understand it, that solution sources the entire script in a subshell (correct?).  Depending on the script, that could have all manor of side-effects (performance of lengthy calculations, files created, deleted, moved... emails sent, etc.).   The approach here, by contrast, avoids that by just sourcing the minimum.  Because this requires just a couple lines of code, not a hundred, this also offers simplicity and clarity.  This method also does not require `eval`.

Comment: Again, (I ran out of characters in the previous comment), I'm sure that your solution fits your requirements superbly.   I'm just pointing out that there may be other use cases with other goals or requirements.

Comment: Agreed, that your solution is much more concise.  However, it does not provided the flexibility that is required.  All the scripts contain functions, so the overhead of reading the file is minimal and a fair trade for flexibility.

Comment: OK.  Your code does have a lot of features that I have not yet fully grokked.  Which flexibility are you referring to?

Comment: well, i don't have to plan ahead for what functions will be required externally.  I can simply call `import file` then call any function from that file as `file func_name` or `import file fun_name` then call that function directly.  This keep things consistent between files so that each file can source only the functions it requires. if two files source func_a and those two files are sourced in the same file the file that fun_a resides in will only be called once.  Now when things get complicated the file may be called hundreds of times but only actually read and sourced once!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116612/discussion-between-arctelix-and-john1024).

Answer (score 1):

1. create standalone shel script that do this

   - will have 2 argument the file name and the function name
   - it will source the input file first
   - it will then use declare -f function name
2. in your code you can include functions like this

   eval "./importfunctions.sh filename functionaname"

**what is happening here :**

step 1 basically read the file and source it in new shell environment . then it will echo the function declaration

step 2 will eval that function into our main code

So final result is as if we wrote just that function in our main script

Comment: I believe this is exactly what i have done in the solution i posted the link to...

Comment: I think it will do exactly the same yes, but the way it is done is different. in your script the part that redfeine the function i didnt understand it and instead of that i suggested to use declare which is clearer

Comment: I tried that out an it is more efficient and works very well for my original specs! However, each file is constructed like a class so that their functions rely on other functions within the file.  There fore i would have to import all the required functions.  The way i'm doing it the function is excited in the context of the file it resides.. I should have included that in the specs.

Comment: @arctelix good point never thought dependencies of the imported function. I think your original solution seems the best so far , I am interested to see if anyone will have something better

Answer (score 1):

When the functions in the script indent untill the closing `}` and all start with the keyword `function`, you can include specific functions without changing the original files:
**largeshell.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

function demo1 {
   echo "d1"
}

function demo2 {
   echo "d2"
}

function demo3 {
   echo "d3"
}

function demo4 {
   echo "d4"
}

echo "Main code of largeshell... "
demo2
```

Now show how to source demo1() and forget demo4():

```
source <(sed -n '/^function demo1 /,/^}/p' largeshell.sh)
source <(sed -n '/^function demo3 /,/^}/p' largeshell.sh)
demo1
demo4
```

Or source all functions in a loop:

```
for f in demo1 demo3; do
   echo sourcing $f
   source <(sed -n '/^function '$f' /,/^}/p' largeshell.sh)
done
demo1
demo4
```

You can make it more fancy when you `source` a special script that will:

- grep all strings starting with `largeshell.`, like `largefile.demo1`
- generate functions like largefile.demo1 that will call demo1
- and source all functions that are called.

Your new script will look like

```
source function_includer.sh
largeshell.demo1
largeshell.demo4
```

EDIT:
You might want to reconsider your requirements.
Above solution is not only slow, but it will also make it hard for the
guys and ladies who made tha largeshell.sh. As soon as they are going to refactor their code or replace it with something in another language,
they have to refactor, test and deploy your code as well.
A better path is extracting the functions from largeshell.sh into some smaller files ("modules"), and put them in a shared directory (shlib?).
With names as sqlutil.sh, datetime.sh, formatting.sh, mailstuff.sh and comm.sh you can pick the includes file you need (and largefile.sh will include them all).

Comment: This was a very interesting approach, but has the same limitation as hani's solution (see comments).  I also suspect that sed is slower then just sourcing the entire file in the subshell.  Thanks for your idea!